# find character format and replace in c#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

How to find character format and replace in c#

I wanna find this in string

```
x[number].
```

My code

```
string input = "23. 11x10.9.1.10x03.9x8"
string okk;
Regex ini = new Regex(input, @"\d");
string lol = "x"+ini+".";
txtOutput.Text = input.Replace(lol, " ");
```

i hope replace to

```
txtOutput --> "23.11x10. 9.1.10x03. 9x8. "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  23. 11x10.9.1.10x03.9x8

Out 23.11x10.  9.1.10x03. 9x8.

```
string input = "23. 11x10.9.1.10x03.9x8";
input = input.Replace(" ", ""); //del blank character
Regex ini = new Regex(@"\d+"); //1-n Numbers
Match match = ini.Match(input);
string lol = "";
while (match.Success) { 
     lol = "x" + match.Value + ".";
     input = input.Replace(lol, lol + " ");
     match = match.NextMatch();
}   

input = input + ". "; //attached . and space, after last character

MessageBox.Show(input);
```

Comment: thks it's work, i wanna ask to you how to make spacing in first number and last number ? for example "#code1 23.11x10. 9.1.10x03. 9x8. #code1"

Comment: i complete my question in this top if my input input = "#code1 23. 11x10.9.1.10x03.9x8 #code1" for get value output -->  "#code1 23.11x10. 9.1.10x03. 9x8. #code1"

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
string input = "23. 11x10.9.1.10x03.9x8";
string txtOutput = Regex.Replace(input, @"(x\d+\.)", "$1 ");
Console.WriteLine(txtOutput);
//=> 23. 11x10. 9.1.10x03. 9x8
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/ErAjC6)

We are matching `(x\d+\.)` using our regex and also capturing matched value. Then we are replacing with `"$1 "` which will add space after same matched text.

Comment: thks sir for your answer

Comment: how to remove 23.(spacing) but not delete x\d+\.(spacing) ?

Comment: number of 23 is not fixed of input that from user input sometime have [number](spac)[dot] sometime is perfect [number][dot] .... I am so sory sir i really want give point for your answer and other answer but i have not enough reputation for that

Comment: ok thks i don't know for accepted answer just need 15 rep.. thank you sir :D